# varnish start failed + nginx

Tags: centos, nginx, varnish

I did install `varnish` with [this guide](https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/redhat).

Then I want to start it, but `FAILD` and I cannot start `varnish`.

I ran it in debug mode and I got this error: `No VCL Available` !

What is the problem here?

Also enabled `varnishlog`, but no error log there.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, path to `default.vcl` was in my website, changed to `etc/varnish/default.vcl` and then worked as well